# Why does 1/inf == 0 but 1/0 != inf?

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

In general, **1/a = b ⟺ 1/b = a**, so if we're letting the reciprocal of infinity be 0, the reciprocal of 0 should be infinity.

It seems strange for Python to use the limit for **1/inf** but not for **1/0**. What is the rationale behind this decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 1/0 can be either +inf (positive) or -inf (negative). 1/inf can only be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, just after I posted this, I answered my own question:

It's because there's no way of knowing if the result should be **+inf** or **-inf**.

As an aside, the IEEE floating point standard does support [positive and negative 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).